# Matrix representation of a triplet state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, group-representations, neutrinos, representation-theory

The $SU(2)$ triplet state is typically given in the fundamental representation as a column vector, e.g. 
\begin{equation} 
\vec{\Delta} = \left( \begin{array}{c} 
\delta^{++}  \\  
\delta^+  \\  
\delta^0 
\end{array} \right) 
\end{equation} 
where I use this notation to be consistent with the references below.

However, I'm reading through papers (in the context of the type II see-saw mechanism, but I don't think it has much relevance) and most references are using what they call the matrix representation of the $SU(2)$ triplet. My instinct was to assume that they were projecting the fundamental representation onto the Pauli matrices:

\begin{equation} 
\Delta \rightarrow \vec{\Delta } \cdot \vec{ \sigma } = \delta ^{++} \sigma _1 + \delta ^+ \sigma _2  + \delta ^0 \sigma _3 
\end{equation}

However, this doesn't quite give me the correct result, which is given by, 
\begin{equation} 
\Delta = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 
\delta ^+ / \sqrt{2}  & \delta ^{ + + } \\  
\delta ^0  & - \delta ^+ / \sqrt{2} 
\end{array} \right) 
\end{equation}

Is there some other way to get this "matrix representation"?

Two sample references where they say they are using the matrix representation can be found [here](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2013/reviews/rpp2013-rev-higgs-boson.pdf) (pg. 124, equation 68) and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.3536) (pg. 4 equation 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the triplet refers to the spin one representation of $SU(2)_L$ of the standard model. Let $I_a$ refer to the generators of $SU(2)_L$. Then the triplet can be organized into a column vector with $I_3$ being diagonal and equal to Diag$(1,0,-1)$. Suppose the triplet has hypercharge $Y$, i.e., the charge associated with $U(1)_Y$. Electroweak symmetry breaking has $SU(2)_L\times U(1)_Y$ broken to $U(1)_{EM}$. The electric charge is given by the formula $Q=I_3+\tfrac12 Y$. If $Q=2$ for the triplet, then we see that $Q=(2,1,0)$ which is written as $(++,+,0)$ and added as a superscript to indicate the charge of a particle in such a triplet. This should explain the notation for $\vec{\Delta}$ that you have given.

Now to go to the matrix representation, one uses the fact that the spin-one representation of $SU(2)$ is also its adjoint representation. Since the three entries in $\vec{\Delta}$ are all $I_3$ eigenstates, in order to write the matrix representation using Pauli sigma matrices, you need to write the Pauli matrices in a basis where they are the analog of eigenstates of $I_3$. Such a basis is given by $\tfrac12\sigma_\pm =\tfrac12( \sigma_1\pm i\sigma_2)$ and $\tfrac12\sigma_3$. So the natural guess would be something like
$$
\Delta \rightarrow \frac12 (\delta^{++}\ \sigma_+ +\delta^+\ \sigma_3 + \delta^0\ \sigma_-)\ .
$$
There will be variations in convention in that $\delta^{++}$ will be paired up with $\sigma_-$ instead of $\sigma_+$ as I have done. I might also be missing some factors of $\sqrt{2}$ but I am sure you get the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you explain what you mean by " you need to write the Pauli matrices in a basis where they are the analogue of eigenstates of $I_3$"? How come $\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{\pm}$ is an analogue of eigenstates of $I_3$?

Comment: It is longish story but I will try to be crisp. While acting on states, we look for eigenvectors of $I_3$: $I_3 |m\rangle = m\ | m\rangle$. The analog in the matrix (adjoint) representation is the commutator $[I_3,M]=m\ M$ as we think of $M$ as operators acting on a vector space (two-dimensional here). Of course, standard normalization implies $I_a \leftrightarrow \tfrac12 \sigma_a$ which is the half I put in.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation_of_a_Lie_algebra

Comment: Thanks again, I will think more about this. I never learned very much about the adjoint representation.