# If we had a Higgs triplet with hypercharge $Y=1$, would we get three Higgs bosons?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, higgs, symmetry-breaking

In the Standard Model, the Higgs field is a doublet of SU(2) and hypercharge $Y=1/2$. We have four real scalar degrees of freedom (since $H$ is a complex doublet); three of these get "eaten" to form the longitudinal polarizations of the $W^±_\mu$ and $Z_\mu$. One scalar remains: the Higgs boson.

What would happen if we modified the Standard Model to have a Higgs triplet with hypercharge $Y=1$? (With the $\tau^a$ being the 3x3 Pauli matrices). Do we have 3 Higgs bosons?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/367660/how-does-a-higgs-triplet-transform-under-su2-l-times-u1-y-when-written-as). Look at the charges of what's eaten and what survives. What are your Goldstone bosons?